# Not able update multiple column data using with column pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Simple example

```
dataDF = spark.createDataFrame([(66, "a", "4"), 
                                (67, "a", "0"), 
                                (70, "b", "4"), 
                                (71, "d", "4"),
                               (71, "e", "4")],
                                ("id", "code", "amt"))
dataDF.withColumn("new_column",
       when((col("code") == "a") | (col("code") == "d"), "A")
      .when((col("code") == "b") & (col("amt") == "4"), "B")
      .otherwise("A1")).show()
```

Output

```
+---+----+---+----------+
| id|code|amt|new_column|
+---+----+---+----------+
| 66|   a|  4|         A|
| 67|   a|  0|         A|
| 70|   b|  4|         B|
| 71|   d|  4|         A|
| 71|   e|  4|        A1|
+---+----+---+----------+
```

Created function

```
def get_delakeys(list_columns,id_no):
    start=[]
    for index,row in dataDF.filter(dataDF.id == id_no).toPandas().iterrows():
        for i in list_columns:

            final = {"keyname" : i,"value" : row[i],"description" : "..."}
            start.append(final)
        #final_val= {"value" : row['Charge_Type']}
#start.append(final_val)
    return start

json_schema_test = StructType([StructField('keyname', StringType(), nullable=False),StructField('value', StringType(),nullable=False),StructField('description',StringType(),nullable=False)])
get_res_udf = udf(get_delakeys, json_schema_test)
```

when i try to add it throws error

```
df_new_test=dataDF.withColumn("new_column",lit(''))
df_new_test1=dataDF.withColumn("new_column",get_res_udf(["code","amt"],col("id")))
```

Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the expected output that you want, as I think a udf is not necessary here and is incredibly slow.

Comment: Hi, you are referring to a dataframe inside of the udf. This may be the cause of pickle error.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe the following, as a udf is possibly unnecessary here:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType

df_new_test = (
    df_new_test
    .groupBy(
        "id",
        "code",
        "amt"
    )
    .agg(
        F.struct(
            F.col("code"),
            F.col("amt"),
            F.lit("...").alias("description")
        )
        .alias("new_column")
    )
)
df_new_test.show()

+---+----+---+-----------+
| id|code|amt| new_column|
+---+----+---+-----------+
| 66|   a|  4|{a, 4, ...}|
| 67|   a|  0|{a, 0, ...}|
| 70|   b|  4|{b, 4, ...}|
| 71|   d|  4|{d, 4, ...}|
| 71|   e|  4|{e, 4, ...}|
+---+----+---+-----------+
```

I can give a better answer if you provide the expected output you require.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. expected output be for new_column based one code and amt==== [{'keyname': 'code', 'value': 'a', 'description': '...'},
 {'keyname': 'amt', 'value': '0', 'description': '...'}]